# Close all tabs of p:accordionPanel on page load

Tags: jsf, primefaces, accordion

Accordionpanel tabs are not closed when moving the second time to the page, even with 
activeIndex="" the tabs are closed only the first time moving to the page.
I'm using Primefaces 3.5 and MyFaces 2.1.5.

```
<p:accordionPanel id="accordionServers" style="width:400px" multiple="true" activeIndex="" cache="false" dynamic="true">
<p:tab title="Tab1"></p:tab>
<p:tab title="Tab2"></p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

What is the simplest workaround?

Comment: already tried and it's not working. In fact then my second tab is openend.

Comment: try activeIndex="-" .it is working for me

Comment: this crashes my webapp

Comment: 4.0? where did you get this version from?

Comment: I have tried activeIndex="-" it's worked. ( Primefaces 3.4)
<p:accordionPanel multiple="true" id="accordionPanel" activeIndex="-"   >

Comment: can you try with 3.5 please?

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
activeIndex="null"
```

It worked just fine !!

Answer (score 2):

activeIndex="-", in Primefaces 3.4, when multiple="true"

```
<p:accordionPanel 
    id="accordionServers" 
    style="width:400px" 
    multiple="true" 
    activeIndex="-" 
    cache="false" 
    dynamic="true">
    <p:tab title="Tab1" />
    <p:tab title="Tab2" />
</p:accordionPanel>
```

Answer (score 2):

In my scenario setting activeIndex="-1" or activeIndex="null" or activeIndex="-" or activeIndex="" did not work.

**I returned -1 from manager bean and it worked. Getter always returns -1 and setter does nothing.**

```
activeIndex="#{managerBean.activeTabIndices}"
```

p.s. I needed all tabs to be always closed initially.

Comment: This is a new question instead of answer. use [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) link to ask new question

Comment: Read again attentively. I gave another possible solution for the problem already being discussed. None of the previous solutions worked for me so I thought how I solved it might help someone.

Answer (score 0):

You can close all tab of an accordion by JavaScript, using JQuery, as the code below.

```
 for (var i = 0; i< $(".ui-accordion-header").size(); i++) {
        PF('accordionWidgetVarName').unselect(i);
 }
```